# Traverse to selectMenu and get id (Javascript \ JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I want to get the selected value of the inputs.
Only if the ascendent class is a specific one - **Q01**.
Assume there is no "name" or "ID" on the select menu as i dont know it at run time.

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/techhausse/p6qfd5f2/1/)

```
<table>
  <TR>
    <td class="Q01" valign="MIDDLE"> <b>01.1 </b>Question 01 </td>
    <TD>
      <SELECT CLASS="selectMenu" ID="" NAME="">
        <OPTION VALUE="">&lt;None&gt;</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="2" SELECTED>2</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="1">1</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <td class="Q01" valign="MIDDLE">      <b>01.1 </b>Question 02    </td>
    <TD NOWRAP>
      <SELECT CLASS="selectMenu" ID="" NAME="">
        <OPTION VALUE="">&lt;None&gt;</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="2">2</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="1">1</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

I have tried `$(".Q01:first").next('select').val();` but it returns `undefined`

EDIT - I changed "input" to "select", my mistake.

ANSWER EDIT - thanks to Hello Cynogenic, i further narrowed it down to what I was after, using `"alert($('.Q01:first').next('td').find('select option:selected').val())` i was returned the selected option from the first select menu.

Comment: This html has no input elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert($(".Q01:first" ).next('td').children().val());
```

Check below link  :-)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/aku4hLzc/2/)

Comment: your answer is the most comprehensive , working thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a spare `</TD>` tag that means your markup is broken.

Assuming you remove the errant tag, this will give you the select element:

```
$('.q1').next('td').find('select');
```

You have to traverse the document step by step.

next() means "find the next element within this container, at this level, if it matches the specified selector"
find() means "search the current element for children matching the specified selector"

Comment: whats the spare tag?

Comment: using the find method I have narrowed down what I want, thanks